# OneToOne Spring JPA MySQL LAZY load N+1 selects

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In my Spring JPA/Data MySQL application I have a following entites:

```
public class Gene implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "uid")
    private String uid;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "gene")
    private GeneStory geneStory;

}
```

and

```
public class GeneStory implements Serializable {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "gene_uid", referencedColumnName = "uid")
    private Gene gene;

}
```

I'm trying to load all `Gene` via

```
Query q = em.createQuery("select g from Gene g")
return q.getResultList();
```

and I get the `N+1 selects problem` with `GeneStory`

Right now on each `Gene` in database I have additional query for `GeneStory` like following:

```
select genestory0_.story_id as story_id1_7_0_ ... from gene_stories genestory0_ where genestory0_.gene_uid=?
```

Lazy load of `GeneStory` doesn't work for some reason.

At the database layer in `gene_storie`s table I also have a constraint -

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_gene_stories_gene_uid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`gene_uid`)
    REFERENCES `gene` (`uid`)
```

How to fix this N+1 selects problem? I don't want to load `GeneStory` together with `Gene`. I need to lazy load them when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per JPA Spec:

> Lazy fetching is a hint to the persistence provider and can be
>   specified by means of the Basic, OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToOne,
>   ManyToMany, and ElementCollection annotations and their XML
>   equivalents
>
> The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider
>   runtime that data must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint
>   to the persistence provider runtime that data should be fetched lazily
>   when it is first accessed. **The implementation is permitted to eagerly**
>   **fetch data for which the LAZY strategy hint has been specified**.

Comment: In other words there is no way to implement a normal bidirectional lazy load for OneToOne in JPA ?

Comment: As it is said according to spec, even though you specified a LAZY fetch on annotation, it is just a hint to your provider. It is up to the provider to follow the hint or override it by eagerly fetching the data. When I say "provider", we talk about any ORM implementation that follow the JPA spec (i.e. Hibernate, EclipseLink etc.).